# best way to create updates and patches in python

Tags: python, setuptools

Say I have a package with a following structure

```
hw
  __init__.py
  hw.py
```

and I have already installed this package in my system. Now I have added another file hw2.py and now the structure looks like this.

```
 hw
    __init__.py
    hw.py
    hw2.py
```

How do I go about distributing this new package, with setuptools? Essentially how does one build and install updates for the package in python with setuptools?

Comment: Generally you'd just distribute the new version, rather than a patch; bump the version number on your PyPI distro and people `pip` installing or upgrading get the latest build unless they explicitly pin it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you'd just distribute the new version, rather than a patch; bump the version number on your PyPI distro and people pip installing or upgrading get the latest build unless they explicitly pin it.